# How to upgrade Openfire from 3.8.2 to 3.10.0?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, xmpp

When I try to upgrade Openfire from 3.8.2 to 3.10.0, it gives the following error.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

```
1. wget http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/openfire_3.10.0_all.deb
2. sudo dpkg -i openfire_3.10.0_all.deb
```

> ```
> (Reading database ... 204041 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to replace openfire 3.10.0 (using openfire_3.10.0_all.deb) ...
> testing JVM in /usr ...
> Shutting down openfire
> Stopped.
> Unpacking replacement openfire ...
> Setting up openfire (3.10.0) ...
> update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/openfire missing LSB information
> update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
> Starting openfire
> nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
>
>
> Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
> ```

I have Googled and came up with [this link](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/43947) but still no solution.

Answer (score 0):

The thread provided in link states this:

- stop the running OpenFire: sudo /etc/init.d/openfire stop , if it doesn't stop then search and kill its process by `sudo kill -9 PID`

to get the PID

```
ps aux | grep openfire
```

the result would be something like:

```
maythux   3541  0.4  0.0 613892 18500 ?        Sl   09:17   0:00 blah blah blah
```

Here the PID is 3541, then to kill this process run the command

```
sudo kill -9 3541
```

- delete all plugins (NOT their data directories): sudo rm
  /var/lib/openfire/plugins/*.jar
- update the old OpenFire using dpkg with the following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i openfire_3.10.0_all.deb
  ```
- if it's not already running, start it again: sudo
  /etc/init.d/openfire start
- After it runs and get into the admin interface try to re-install the
  plugins you had, the settings will be retained
- go to Security Settings and make the checkmark at "Accept self-signed
  certificates. Server dialback over TLS is now available."

answer was quoted from [here](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/43947)

Comment: i tried this "etc/init.d/openfire stop
Shutting down openfire
Stopped."

Comment: @kamlesh.bar check the edit

Comment: Still same error no solution

Comment: did you stop it correctly?

Comment: yes it says openfire stopped

Comment: did you delete the plugins?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24196/discussion-between-kamlesh-bar-and-maythux).